# C++: Beginning input into a string vector with a punctuation character terminates program, throws 'std::length_error'

Tags: c++, string, exception, vector, runtime-error

In my program, I have an empty string vector that gets filled in via user input. The program is meant to take numbers from user input, then sort those numbers in order from smallest to largest (the data type is string to make it easier to check for undesired inputs, such as whitespaces, letters, punctuation marks, etc.). If the first character for the first input is a punctuation mark (for example, if the first thing the user submits to the program is ",45"), the program first outputs the following strings I wrote:

> Error: Invalid input2.

> Please input an integer. When finished providing numbers to organize, input any character that isn't an integer:

and then immediately follows with an error message:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'

> what():  vector::_M_default_append

How can I prevent the error from occurring & terminating the program? Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> vect;    //Container for user inputs. String chosen instead of int to make input filtering easier.
    string input;           //Variable for user inputs
    int intInput;           //Variable to convert stringstream to int
    int entries = 0;        //Variable to track quantity of valid user inputs
    int empty = 0;          //Variable to track invalid user inputs to be deleted from the vector
    int i = 0;              //Variable for vector size
    int x = 0;              //Variable for while loop condition

    while (x < 1)           //x is permanently 0, loop will only terminate with break statement
    {
        cout << "Please input an integer. When finished providing numbers to organize, input any character that isn't an integer:\n";
        vect.resize(i++);
        getline(cin, input);
        cout << endl;

        stringstream ss(input);
        if (ss >> intInput) //Check if stringstream content can be converted to int
        {
            if (ss.eof()) //Check if stringstream content is only integers
            {
                vect.push_back(input); 
                entries++;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Error: Invalid input1.\n\n";
                empty++;
            }
        }   
        else if (entries < 1) //Ensures the user submits at least 1 integer before attempting to organize the numbers
        {
            cout << "Error: Invalid input2.\n\n";
            empty++;
            i = -1;
            continue;
        }   
        else if (entries >= 1)
        {
            break;
        }   
    }
    
    cout << "All done? Organizing numbers!\n\n";
    
    sort(vect.begin(), vect.end(), [](string a, string b) //Function converts strings to ints, then sorts from smallest to largest
    {
        int aInt = 0;
        int bInt = 0;
        
        try 
        {
            aInt = stoi(a); 
        } 
        catch (invalid_argument){} 

        try 
        {
            bInt = stoi(b); 
        } 
        catch (invalid_argument){}
        
        return aInt < bInt;
    });

    vect.erase (vect.begin(), vect.begin() + empty); //Erases lines of whitespace left by invalid user inputs
    
    for (int j = 0; j < vect.size(); j++)
    {   
        cout << vect[j] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `std::invalid_argument` is polymorphic. Catch it by `const&`

Comment: What do you think happens if you do `i = -1; vect.resize(i++);`? You do know how the postfix increment works, right?

Comment: Problem fixed by changing `i++` to `++i` and deleting `i = -1`. `i = -1` is from a previous iteration of the program to clear invalid starting entries from the vector (vector.clear() didn't work), but it seems that changes made to the program since then have rendered it unneeded.